# Oracle: Insert Rows from Select with New Sequence IDs

Tags: oracle

I have a table `TABLE_T` with columns (`ID`, `COL2`, `COL3`, `COL4`, ...) and a Sequence on `TABLE_T.ID` called `TABLE_SEQUENCE`.

For specific IDs, I'd like to duplicate those rows where all column values will come from the existing rows selected by those IDs, while the IDs themselves will be new from the Sequence.

What's the syntax for that? Simple question, but hard to find the answer.

Example:

```
6, 'Test1', 'Test2', ...
7, 'Test3', 'Test4', ...
8, 'Test5', 'Test6', ...
```

for these `(ID in 6,7,8)` I would like to automatically insert:

```
TABLE_SEQUENCE.NEXTVAL, 'Test1', 'Test2', ..
TABLE_SEQUENCE.NEXTVAL, 'Test3', 'Test4', ..
TABLE_SEQUENCE.NEXTVAL, 'Test5', 'Test6', ..
```

and the result would be

```
3411, 'Test1', 'Test2', ...
3412, 'Test3', 'Test4', ...
3413, 'Test5', 'Test6', ...
```

Comment: Huh?  Can you please show an example with data?

Comment: I showed an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First create a query that will display the rows you want:

```
SELECT
    Id,
    col1, col2, col3, ....., colN
FROM table
WHERE /* the condition which selects rows you want */
   id >= 6 AND id <= 10
```

then replace `ID` column with `TABLE_SEQUENCE.NEXTVAL` and prepend the whole query with `INSTERT` statement:

```
INSERT INTO table( Id, col1, col2, col3, ....., colN )
SELECT
    TABLE_SEQUENCE.NEXTVAL,
    col1, col2, col3, ....., colN
FROM table
WHERE /* the condition which selects rows you want */
   id >= 6 AND id <= 10
```

Comment: There's an even faster way to get the SELECT, "Export" in the Client, lol.